# How do I specify regular expressions for CTest

Tags: regex, cmake, ctest

I want to run only a certain selection of tests.
From the [CMake Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html) I found `-R <regex>` and `-E <regex>`, so I can run selections like `ctest -E UNWANTED_TESTS -R WANTED_TESTS` but I would like to be more expressive, specifically I want to combine two strings by *or*.
For example, how do I run tests containing "AAAA" but neither containing "BBBB" nor "CCCC"?
Generally, where may I learn more about this kind of regular expressions?

Comment: Thanks for your question, I felt like I was the only one who couldn't find these informations !

Answer (score 4):

`ctest -E "BBBB|CCCC" -R "AAAA"` did the job. [POSIX](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) seems to set the standard, for other unix-utilities as well.

Comment: It doesn't look like `-R` and `-E` can be combined in a reasonable way. With ctest 3.26.3, when the sets described by `-R` and `-E` overlap, ctest runs all tests `-R` specifies, not excluding any test specified by `-E`. The order of the arguments doesn't matter either.

Comment: Actually, it appears to work exactly as you'd expect with -R then followed by -E. It includes those specific tests but then excludes the ones specified. I was able to confirm this behavior, I had 3 tests with a certain prefix. I -R "prefix" then -E "specific_test" and only 2 tests were run.